# Использование Auth0 в России

Tags: javascript, auth, юридические-аспекты, auth0

В своем сервисе использую авторизацию через Auth0.

Насколько я понимаю, сервис позволяет хранить данные о пользователях только в европе или США.

Я совсем в этом не понимаю, но, вроде как, по российскому законодательству, я должен хранить данные в России. Своя БД приложения действительно находится в России (в яндекс облаке).

Вопросы:

- Нарушаю ли я что-то, используя Auth0?
- Если практика проверки соблюдения этих требований у мелких компаний. Как это можно проверить?
- Есть ли какие либо сервисы авторизации уровня Auth0, хранящие данные о пользователях в России. Или, может, можно заставить  Auth0 использовать мою БД?

Answer (score 0):

Auth0 позволяет использовать свою БД, но только в платной версии. См. детали в [инструкции](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db)